# Laravel - How to make students not to score beyond the max mark

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application project. In the project I have these tables:

```
class SubjectCategory extends Model
{   
  protected $table = 'subject_categories';
  protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'parent_id',
              'max_mark',
          ];

   public function children()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SubjectCategory', 'parent_id');
   }

  public function exams()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Exam');
  }
}

class Exam extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'exams';
  protected $fillable = [
              'subject_category_id',
              'student_id',
              'student_mark',
              'subject_name',
          ];

  public function subjectcategory()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SubjectCategory','subject_category_id');
  }  
}
```

SubjectCategory is an hierarchical table. Only the parent have the max_mark

Here is the Controller

```
public function create()
{
 $categories = SubjectCategory::with('children')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('exams.create')
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
public function store(StoreExamRequest $request)
{

    $exam = new Exam();
    $exam->stubject_category_id     = $request->stubject_category_id;
    $exam->student_id              = $student_id;
    $exam->student_mark             = $request->student_mark;
    $exam->save();
        return redirect()->route('exams.index');
}
```

view blade

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
         <div class="card card-secondary">
          <form  method="POST" action="{{route('exams.store')}}">
          @csrf
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Subject Category:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="subject_category" class="form-control" name="subject_category_id">
                <option value="">Select Subject Category</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                  <option disabled="disabled" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Subject Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="subject_name" placeholder="Enter Subject Name here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Mark Obtained:</label>
              <input  type="number" name="student_mark" placeholder="Enter Mark Obtained here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  


       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>           
       
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
   </div>
   <!--/.col (left) -->
  </div>
```

Subjects are categorized. From SubjectCategory, the parent subject have sub subjects as children. Only the Parent Subject Category have the Maximum Obtainable Score (Max Mark).

From the Exam (subject_category_id) dropdownlist contains all the children fields from subject_categories. What I want to achieve is this:

When Subject Category is selected from the dropdownlist, the system goes to the exams table. It displays total student_mark based on student_id and subject_category_id.

In each subject, the student accumulated mark cannot be more than the max_mark in the parent subject_category.

When the user tries to enter data into student_mark text field, the application adds the value in the text field to the student aggregate. If the result is more than the max_mark in subject_categories (SubjectCategory) based on the parent max_mark, then an error message is displayed.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable in a couple of different ways; you could use validation to prevent someone entering a value over the max mark, or if they do enter a value over the max mark then you just silently reduce it back to the max mark.

I would suggest you take the validation approach and to do this you would need to use a custom validation rule.

You can read up on the documentation for how to create one (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) but the implementation might look a little something like this:

```
// Inside a form request (or you could use inline validation in your controller
'student_mark' => [new NotOverMaxMark($this->input('subject_category_id'))]
```

Then for the rule itself might look a little something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\SubjectCategory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class NotOverMaxMark implements Rule
{
    private $subjectCategory;

    public function __construct($subjectCategoryId)
    {
        $this->subjectCategory = SubjectCategory::findOrFail($subjectCategoryId);
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value <= $this->subjectCategory->max_mark;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must not be higher than the max mark.';
    }
}
```

The above is an example of how you might do this, you may need to tweak the imports or implementation to your needs.